# How do I create a report using a crosstab query?

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2013

When I try to use the report wizard on a crosstab query, none of the fields show up. I tried googling this, but unfortunately, I'm having no luck finding something that works for me. Here is my crosstab sql code. This report will be pulled up from a form.

```
PARAMETERS [Forms]![SSIReports]![txtEndDate] DateTime, [Forms]![SSIReports]![txtStartDate] DateTime;
TRANSFORM Max(MnthlyAmalgamated.NumberOf) AS MaxOfNumberOf
SELECT MnthlyAmalgamated.Type
FROM MnthlyAmalgamated
GROUP BY MnthlyAmalgamated.Type
PIVOT MnthlyAmalgamated.Project;
```

I realize the issue here is the variable columns, but I have no clue what to do about it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an article on how to deal with this:

[Creating an Annual 12 Month Summary Report without VBA Code by Creatively Using a Microsoft Access Crosstab Query](http://www.fmsinc.com/MicrosoftAccess/query/crosstab-report/index.html)